# ES6 module: re-export as object

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6

I have moduleA which exports some functions:

```
// moduleA.js
export function f1() {...}
export function f2() {...}
```

Is there any way to re-export all exports of moduleA in moduleB and make it looks like one object:

```
// moduleB.js
export * as a from 'moduleA';  // pseudo code, doesn't work
```

So that I can use it in this way?

```
// main.js
import {a} from 'moduleB';
a.f1();
a.f2();
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The syntax is not supported yet but there is [a proposal for it](https://github.com/leebyron/ecmascript-more-export-from#proposed-additions).

You can use it now with Babel.js or simply do:

```
import * as a from '...';
export {a};
```

Comment: For anyone looking - the proposal is still at stage 1. It's not included in `babel-preset-env` or `babel-preset-latest`. You will need to install it separately: http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-export-extensions/

Comment: Original proposal was redrawn and is replaced by: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-export-ns-from

Answer (score -2):

**file1.js**

```
export let uselessObject = {
  con1 : function () {
    console.log('from file1.js')
  }
}
```

**file2.js**

```
import { uselessObject } from './file1.js'

uselessObject.con2 = function(){
  console.log('from file2.js ')
}

export { uselessObject } from './file1.js'
```

**Index.js**

```
import { uselessObject } from './file2.js'
uselessObject.con1()
uselessObject.con2()
```

**Output**

```
from file1.js
from file2.js
```

Comment: That would require changing the structure of `file1` and `file2`

Comment: its working code .. solving the purpose .. what more you want

Comment: can you write some good / improved code ... i will delete this post

Comment: From those Felix two lines code i was hardly able to understand what a what a working solution would look like , so i wrote this post that contains working code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144173/discussion-between-vijay-and-bergi).